# With the new Imgur upload how do I upload from a URL?

Tags: support, uploader

I want to take an image address from online and put the picture into my Stack Exchange answer.

I used to be able to paste the image URL and it would be uploaded to Imgur and inserted into my post.

Now I don't see how to do this any more.

Comment: TL;DR: click the image upload icon then paste the URL. You don't see anywhere it's possible, but now it works, as a hidden feature.